# How do I get started modeling data with A-frame?

Tags: data-visualization, mozilla, aframe, graph-visualization, webvr

For a beginner, how do I model simple data nodes and relationships using A-frame. I'd like to create a rudimentary VR visualization? Can I upload a file, what format would it be, what else do I need to do? Thanks for any help to get started or links!

Answer (score 0):

Some people in the d3.js (data visualization library) community have been playing using it with A-Frame. There are lots of examples on http://blockbuilder.org/search#text=aframe . JavaScript and d3.js can take and load any file format to be parsed, most common is JSON and CSV.

I also have a visualization using d3.js + A-Frame at https://ngokevin.github.io/kframe/scenes/statistics-dashboard/ for calendar heatmap.

Ben Pyrik has some components as well, such as for scatterplots: https://github.com/bryik/aframe-scatter-component

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input!